# adding two vales to one cell of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want each cell of my matrix/table to contain two values.
e.g 2,1 2,2 2,3
can anyone show me how to do it in R

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please remember when posting questions to provide a reproducible example, to show what you have tried, and to show the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

To have two numeric values in a single matrix element, you can use a list.

```
(m <- as.matrix(list(c(2, 1),  c(2, 2),  c(2, 3))))
#      [,1]     
# [1,] Numeric,2
# [2,] Numeric,2
# [3,] Numeric,2
```

Then you can access the values via

```
m[, 1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3
```

or

```
m[1, ][[1]]
# [1] 2 1
```

etc. Another option is to use a character vector of pasted values

```
matrix(paste(c(2, 2, 2),  c(1, 2, 3), sep = ","), ncol = 1)
#      [,1] 
# [1,] "2,1"
# [2,] "2,2"
# [3,] "2,3"
```